# Why I should specific class B parameters type when defining a parameter type constraint in a class A based on B's type?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics

I got two bases classes `A` and `B`; `B` is related to `A` by composition. Also, both classes have constraints on type parameters (generic classes), and in this case `class A` is constraining one of its parameter type to `B`'s type. So my question is... when constraining `class A` parameter's type to `B`'s type, **why I should specify the parameter's types for class B as well?** I only see that I must provide `B` parameter types when I would inherit the `class B`, not when its type it's being used for parameter type constraints in a class.

Check a code snippet that illustrates what I'm explaining above:

```
public abstract class B<TParameter, TResponse>
   where TParameter: FooParameter
   where TResponse: FooResponse
{

}

public abstract class A<T, TB>
  where T: class
  where TB: B /*compilation error because B types must be provided... I must define parameter types for class B*/
{
    public TB B {get; set;}

    public A()
    {
        //instantiate B property
    }
}

public class FooParameter {}

public class FooResponse {}
```

Comment: Because `B` isn't a type. `B<TC, TD>` is a type.

Comment: I did this a bunch of times and it inspired me to write [an article](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html). It's not to say that types with a few generic arguments and inheritance are somehow wrong, but they have a way of sending us down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a generic type, you're creating a conceptual "template" more than a complete type. It can only become a complete type when you specify the missing pieces in the template: the concrete types.

Type constraints are there so the compiler can add some type-checking. Even if you don't know the *exact* type that's going to be used, if it inherits from a base, you know what base members are available to your code. If you try to constrain a type parameter with a generic type **without** type arguments, the compiler doesn't have enough information to understand what methods will actually be available.

As an example, if we replace `TB: B` with the type `TB: List<T>`, the compiler would not know what the list is of. Methods like `Add(T)` and `Remove(T)` couldn't be compiled against, because `T` would be unknown.

**For type constraints to be valuable, they must constrain the type system in such a way as to add useful information. The only way for that information to be useful is for the type to be concretely specified.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   public abstract class A<T, TB, C, D>
      where T : class
      where C : FooParameter
      where D : FooResponse
      where TB : B<C,D>    {
      public TB B { get; set; }

      public A()
      {
         //instantiate B property
      }
   }
```

You need to be able to define all of the types that a generic needs at compile time, which you can as above.